# Installing nfs-server package

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, cluster

To make a long story short, I have a small cluster that I will be setting up as an MPICH cluster. However, the cluster will not have an internet connect so, I will have to transfer the files via usb drive.

I was wondering if anyone knows where the packages are for installing nfs-server, nfs-client, and keychain?

Comment: Start with `apt-cache search nfs|grep -i nfs` and `apt-cache search keychain`